# Android studio not opening

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

My Operation system is 64bit window operation system, I have properly installed Java SDK
but whenever I am clicking on launcher icon Android studio not proceeding further after this screen, Please help

Comment: try uninstalling and re-installing

Comment: See if you have the project module tree by pressing `alt+1`

Comment: already tried, but that didn't work!

Comment: @Enzokie alt+1 is not working either

Comment: Invalidate caches and restart?

Comment: Can you recall if you ever press the `cancel` button while Android Studio is doing some setups?

Comment: @Enzokie I can't recall. Is there is any other way to restart android studio?

Comment: @Enzokie even file options are not clickable. I even restarted computer but that didn't work!

Comment: Uninstall/Reinstall is the last option.

Comment: See this little red exclamation mark in the lower right corner? Click on it and an error message should be shown.